# SSO withh KeyCloak from FrontEnd app with Liferay 7.4 as Headless CMS

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, liferay, headless-cms

This is the scenario. I have a Liferay 7.4 CE configured to log in with KeyCloak. At this point every thing is fine. I can create a user un KC and it is imported into LR seamlessly.

On the other hand, I am developing a FrontEnd app (Python + Flask) which consumes Liferay's HeadLess API.

I can log The front-end app with KC but I have never logged  this user in Liferay, It has never been imported into LR from KC. So, even if I log the user in the FrontEnd app against KC, I am not able to get data with the headless API as far as this user has not been imported into LR.

How could I trigger the propagation of the user from KC to LR when I sign-in in the FrontEnd app?

I hoped it would be imported when making the first request to the HeadLess API with the JWT token.